# Error: Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: base

Tags: linux, server, centos5

I need some help please, I am trying to install `yum update` in CentOS 5.9 but I get error

```
> Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, kmod Loading mirror speeds from cached
> hostfile YumRepo Error: All mirror URLs are not using ftp, http[s] or
> file.  Eg. Invalid release/ removing mirrorlist with no valid mirrors:
> /var/cache/yum/base/mirrorlist.txt Error: Cannot find a valid baseurl
> for repo: base
```

please help me how to fix this

**update content of CentOS-Base.repo**

```
   [base]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Base
#mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=os
baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/os/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-5
exclude=redhat-logos php53*

#released updates
[updates]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Updates
#mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=updates
baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/updates/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-5
exclude=redhat-logos php53*

#additional packages that may be useful
[extras]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Extras
#mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=extras
baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/extras/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-5
exclude=redhat-logos php53*

#additional packages that extend functionality of existing packages
[centosplus]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Plus
#mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=centosplus
baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/centosplus/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=0
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-5
exclude=redhat-logos php53*

#contrib - packages by Centos Users
[contrib]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Contrib
#mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=5$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=contrib
baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/contrib/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=0
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-5
exclude=redhat-logos php53*
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 12):

This is because Centos 5 is deprecated and requires manual update of the Base repo file to point everything to the Centos vault.

Source: http://realtechtalk.com/Centos_59_Working_Vault_Repo_file-1921-articles

Backup your /etc/yum.repos.d/Centos-Base.repo

**Replace with the following will get you going again:**

```
# CentOS-Base.repo
#
# The mirror system uses the connecting IP address of the client and the
# update status of each mirror to pick mirrors that are updated to and
# geographically close to the client.  You should use this for CentOS updates
# unless you are manually picking other mirrors.
#
# If the mirrorlist= does not work for you, as a fall back you can try the
# remarked out baseurl= line instead.
#
#

[base]
name=CentOS-5.9 - Base
#mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=5.9&arch=$basearch&repo=os
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/5.9/os/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-5

#released updates
[updates]
name=CentOS-5.9 - Updates
#mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=5.9&arch=$basearch&repo=updates
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/5.9/updates/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-5

#additional packages that may be useful
[extras]
name=CentOS-5.9 - Extras
#mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=5.9&arch=$basearch&repo=extras
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/5.9/extras/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-5

#additional packages that extend functionality of existing packages
[centosplus]
name=CentOS-5.9 - Plus
#mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=5.9&arch=$basearch&repo=centosplus
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/5.9/os/$basearch/centosplus/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=0
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-5

#contrib - packages by Centos Users
[contrib]
name=CentOS-5.9 - Contrib
#mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=5.9&arch=$basearch&repo=contrib
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/5.9/os/$basearch/contrib/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=0
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-5
```

Comment: Many thanks for your helpful answer !

Comment: Also works for centos 4.8
you just have to replace $releasever with 4.8 and mirror.centos.org/centos with vault.centos.org

Answer (score 2):

This might be caused by two possibilities.

**1. Repo too old to find**

Base on your centos version, I tried to find the os via the [link](http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5.9/). And getting this information from readme file.

> This directory (and version of CentOS) is deprecated.  For normal users,
>       you should use /5/ and not /5.9/ in your path. Please see this FAQ
>       concerning the CentOS release scheme:
>
> https://wiki.centos.org/FAQ/General
>
> If you know what you are doing, and absolutely want to remain at the 5.9
>       level, go to http://vault.centos.org/ for packages. Please keep in mind that 5.9 no longer gets any updates

In this link, it suggest you to find old version via another [link](http://vault.centos.org/5.9/). Thus, you need to modify **CentOS-Base.repo**.

Replacing all `http://mirror.centos.org/centos/***` into `http://vault.centos.org/***`.

*for example:*

```
Original: baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/os/$basearch/
New:      baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/$releasever/os/$basearch/
```

---

**2. Network Issue**

checking the `mirrorlist server` is accessible.

```
$ ping mirrorlist.centos.org
```

If you might meet the error message below.

```
ping: unknown host mirrorlist.centos.org
```

To solve this, adding a valid nameserver into `resolv.conf` (use sudo if you are not root user)

```
$ echo nameserver 8.8.8.8 > /etc/resolv.conf
```

Comment: I tried to ping ,this is the reulst 64 bytes from 108-43-236-85.rev.customer-net.de (85.236.43.108): icmp_seq=2 ttl=53 time=364 ms

Comment: Can you provide the content of your `/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo`? The repo might be too old, thus you can not find them in the mirrorlist server.

Comment: this is the result http://vault.centos.org/centos/5/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404: Not Found
Trying other mirror.
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: base. Please verify its path and try again

Comment: I dont want to get updates I only want to download some packages need for my application to run but it wont allow me

Comment: @jemz instead of that link, please try [http://vault.centos.org/5.9/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml](http://vault.centos.org/5.9/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml), your current repo's baseurl doesn't give you proper information, you must need to fix them first.